# Signals work with the existing *ngIf directive in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

**HTML CODE**

```
 <div *ngIf="count() <= 4; else greaterthan4">This is less than 4</div>
```

**TS CODE**

```
  count = signal<number>(1);
```

This is working.
Old structure directives support signals as well.
Did angular add support for this?

Comment: At the end of the day `signal` is just a function. So there is nothing not to support.